# MySQL Error #: 1064 with sql version 5.6.44

Tags: mysql

Hi I am getting this error in mySql for this query below. Can anybody help me with this.
Thanks.

```
MySQL Error:


190

SQL:
            SELECT `pid`, `pushbadge`, `pushalert`, `pushsound`
            FROM `apns_devices`
            WHERE `pid` IN ()
                AND `status`='active';
```

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')
>                 AND `status`='active'' at line 3 Error #: 1064

Comment: The `IN ()` cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add some values into statement `IN ()` like this:

```
    SELECT `pid`, `pushbadge`, `pushalert`, `pushsound`
    FROM `apns_devices`
    WHERE `pid` IN (1,2,3)
        AND `status`='active';
```

See more http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx